# How to code a if-statement for asking drinking age

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm writing a code to determine if someone can enter a club and whether or not they can drink at the club. I was wondering if I am doing this right, and if there is a better way to write the code. Thanks.

```
public class SoloJava {

    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
        int age = 17;
        if (age >= 18) {
            System.out.println("You can enter");
        }
        if (age < 18) {
            System.out.println("You can not enter");
        }
        if (age >= 21) {
            System.out.println("You can drink");
        } else if (age <= 21) {
            System.out.println("You can not drink");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pro tip: format your code in a readable way. Let your IDE do this.

Comment: Better way? yes -- format your code according to Java and your class standards. Does it work? Test it

Comment: I've formatted your code for you, but in the future, you'll want to learn Java code formatting rules and apply them. Doing this will make your code easier for others (including us and your instructors) to read and understand.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels "Doing this will make your code easier" for *you* (OP) to read too!

Comment: Note that `if (age <= 21)` is redundant, you already checked if age is superior or equal to 21. You can just use `<` or `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

noob here, trying to help. From what I understand there are 3 possibilities.

1. Can't enter (younger than 18 years old)
2. May enter but can't get a drink (younger than 21 but still over 18)
3. Can enter and have a drink (over 21 years old)

Therefore I think that it would be best to minimize the number of if statements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int age = 20;

    if (age<18){
        System.out.println("You cannot enter");
    }
    else if(age>=18 && age<=21){ //checks if his/her age is between 18 and 21
        System.out.println("You may enter but you cannot drink");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You may enter and have a drink");
    }


}
```